# How do I add an equalizer to my discord music bot in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

Using the standard way of playing audio with opus audio and ffmpeg, is there a way I can change the pitch, speed, bass, etc. of the music?

Comment: If so I don't think that you would be able to use the provided discord.js methods, you would have to write your own so you can access those specific features of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it with using `ytdl-core-discord` not a equalizer command that i know of but it is possible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?